# Java eliminate unallowed chars in html string

Tags: java, html, character-encoding, rtf

i am facing with a very difficult problem, which is following:

I have a number of HTML-formatted Strings. they were generated by a Document-Element, where the text was edited in RTF and saved in HTML (to display it on a website).

the problem now is, that some RTF-Elements which are parset to HTML seems to be unusable in html, which leads it to crash. One of the in html disallowed chars is e.g. the **%0b**

according to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm it has no function, or i can't figure out why it is needed (in fact, it isn't even copyable).

My question now is: Is there a function out there (I already searched) which is able to eliminate all non-html characters of such a formatted rtf2html-string?

I just need to eliminate them when the html is loaded, so there aren't any display problems

Comment: What is the exact error message from the "crasch"? Can you also post a relevant snippet of your HTML and also the head (with the encoding information).

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use methods provided by Apache Commons Lang

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
String afterDecoding = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(beforeDecoding);
```

Credit to: @jlordo

Or you can use `replaceAll("%0b", "");`